# Handle click with element in React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events, this

I am new to TypeScript and React and I have an event that I need to know the element that selected it so I can move another element near it on the page but I am having some trouble getting it to work in React TypeScript.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import React from "react";
import './BenefitHeader.css';
import BenefitType from "./BenefitType";
import BenefitSelectIndicator from './BenefitSelectIndicator';

interface State {
  left?: number;
}

export default class BenefitHeader extends React.Component<State> {
  constructor(state:State) {
    super(state)
    this.state = {
      left: 0
    }
    this.handleSelected = this.handleSelected.bind(this)
  }
  
  handleSelected = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=> {
    const newValue = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(newValue);
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="BenefitTitle">
          <span>Benefit</span>
        </div>
        <BenefitType name="Purchase" onClick={this.handleSelected}/>
        <BenefitType name="Purchase" onClick={this.handleSelected}/>
        <BenefitSelectIndicator color="black" width={100}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And handleSelected is never called in its current form, I have tried making `onClick` into `onClick={this.handleSelected(this)}` but I run into issues with typing in TypeScript.

Updated:
Adding `BenefitType`:

```
import React from "react";
import './BenefitType.css';
import BenefitSelectIndicator from './BenefitSelectIndicator';


interface Props {
  name: string,
  onClick: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}

interface State {
  isSelected: boolean;
}

export default class BenefitType extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="BenefitTypeTitle">
        <span className="BenefitTypeTitle purchase">
          {this.props.name}
        </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your `BenefitType` component look like?

Comment: I think you have problem in `BenefitType` component because I've tried your code in `sandbox` and it works fine when I replaced `BenefitType` with `Button`.

So can you please share `BenefitType` component.

Comment: @AlexWayne thanks for taking a look I have updated to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BenefitType` is a custom component. It's not calling your `onClick` because `BenefitType` doesn't put the click handler on anything.

You can pass an `onClick` prop to a custom component, but, eventually, that function needs to be set to an actual html element to work.

To implement the `onClick` prop properly `BenefitType` needs to do something like:

```
export default class BenefitType extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="BenefitTypeTitle" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        <span className="BenefitTypeTitle purchase">
          {this.props.name}
        </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

Also, your click handler is typed `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` which is the event for an `<input>` element getting a new vale. This is not the right event.

The correct event type is:

```
React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>
```

You can discover this by adding a dummy `onClick` handler like:

```
onClick={(event) => undefined}
```

And hovering over `event` to see its type.

And to get the `getBoundingClientRect` you must use the `currentTarget` property of the event:

```
e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Comment: Thanks! I gave that a go but am running into some typing issues. After changing to `onClick: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>) => void` I get an type issue of `Type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.` so I tried `MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>` but that doesnt seem to give me the target I need and the`BenefitHeader` now complains that  `Type '(event: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>) => void'`

Comment: So I tried `ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>` and it also complains that `Type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>'.` So Im kind of stuck in a circle with what I should actually be using.

Comment: Do you need the event object? Because you can just leave it off the argument list and your life will probably be simpler.

Comment: I don't think so- I just need the element so I can get the location of it.

Comment: In that case you do need the event. I've updated my answer. A ref may also work, but that might be more hairy.